Is there some difference in the way the last of the Worricker trilogy was produced, or is owned or licensed?
I've always enjoyed Bill Nighy and Nighy's Johnny Worricker in the Worricker trilogy by David Hare:

2011: Page Eight
2014: Turks & Caicos
2014: Salting the Battlefield

From where I live at least, only the final "Salting the Battlefield" is available on Apple TV. (screenshot to support my assertion) It seems odd to make only one of a trilogy available.
So I'm wondering: Is there some difference in the way the last of the Worricker trilogy  was produced, or is owned or licensed?
